# Is there a standardized approach of retrievening credentials for Neovim Lua plugins

Tags: security, lua, neovim

The [sonarlint.nvim](https://gitlab.com/schrieveslaach/sonarlint.nvim) should offer in the `setup` call a possibility provide connection properties to a remote server a.k.a [connected mode](https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/latest/user-guide/sonarlint-connected-mode/).

> SonarLint's Connected Mode connects SonarLint to your SonarQube project and provides additional benefits you won't get by using SonarLint or SonarQube alone.

For the connected mode an API token is required which could lead following syntax:

```lua
require('sonarlint').setup({
   -- …
   connected_mode = {
      ['https://sonarcloud.io'] = {
         token = "my super secret token",
         -- … other stuff
      }
   }
})
```

Now, I'm wondering what is a good and **secure** way of retrieving the token from some secure location because Neovim users are likely to version control such file in a dotfiles repo. I'm aware of using environment variables, e.g. you can do that securely with [chezmoi](https://chezmoi.io/), but is there a native integration with a secure store such as secret-tool within the Neovim Lua API?

Comment: Just store it in a local file.

Comment: I my personal setup I would use chezmoi to define a env variable securely and load that value in my lua setup. However, is there a recommended way or even support in Neovim? At least that is the essence of the question.